# ¿Cómo graficar números decimales almacenados en una lista?

Tags: python

Mi código lee los datos recibidos a través del puerto usb en tiempo real y los almacena.
Los datos que recibo contienen 22 bytes (Ej. b'$-26.3 dBm30.6 mVpp$'), de los cuales solo me interesa el valor de los dBm. Por eso uso '''dBm = valores[1:6]''' y los almaceno en una lista llamada 'lista1'.
Cuando muestro la lista en una gráfica, los valores del eje Y no salen ordenados. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo sin tener que ordenar la lista previamente, ya que son datos en tiempo real?¿Debo eliminar la parte decimal?
Éste es mi código:
[image: Código]
y esta es la gráfica que obtengo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: creo que la única forma de hacerlo es ordenando la lista. Desde cierta versión de python (no recuerdo cual) los datos se almacenan según su orden de insersion

Comment: Publica el código como texto para empezar ...

Comment: [¿Por qué no deberías compartir código como imagen?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976). Por favor, pulsa en [edit] y agrega el código _como texto, con formato_,

Comment: Hola Carlos, es casi seguro que es un error por tipo de dato, lo más probable es que al estar extrayendo el dato lo estas guardando como un `string` (puedes verificar con un `type(dBM)` ). Intenta transformando el dato en uno de tipo float ->  `dBm = float(valores[1:6])`

Comment: @arce.est muchas gracias por tu comentario. Era ese mi fallo y ahora la gráfica ya se muestra correctamente. :)